# Cfbuilder 3 search for a file with specific text inside a folder

Tags: coldfusion

In Cfbuilder 2 we used to have a search functionality using which we can search for all the files containing a specific keyword or text inside them in any selected folder (not only the project folders or workspace in CfBuilder).

In CfBuilder 3, I cannot find that functionality. It seems that we can only search inside the projects open in the builder.

Is there any way to get the functionality back in CfBuilder 3.

Answer (score 4):

It's still in exactly the same place it was before.

1. Select the directory in the Navigator view
2. Press CTRL-H or Search > Search from the menu
3. Select "Selected Resource" as the Scope

This is exactly how it behaved in previous versions of CFB.

[image]

Comment: Can you select multiple projects with your approach? I do not know that as i am using Express Edition of CFBuilder.

Comment: This is a different question. A folder is a folder: it's a file-system concept, and exists outside the concept of Eclipse projects.

Comment: Should also be noted this is functionality in Eclipse, not necessarily CF Builder. If you were using Eclipse to do Java or Grails work, the steps would be the same.

Comment: And, yes, this will work across projects. You can even select individual folders within a project to search.

Comment: For whatever record, Ctrl H is the most likely setting for Find&Replace, Ctrl F is Find, F3 is Find Next. I much much much appreciate programs that stick to defaults like that and loathe programs that deviate for different's sake.

Comment: Hey Guys. This works only for folders/projects in Navigator window. In Cfbuilder 2 we can select any folder in any drive without worrying about whether  the folder is in Navigator or not. I am unable to find this functionality in Cfbuilder 3